# Access denied on google app engine when upload file on Amazon with used of AWS SDK for Java

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, file-upload, amazon-s3

I am using gwt 2.4, GAE 1.7.3 and jre 1.7,in development mode my code working with used of filter tag which is given in [link](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8166). When I uploaded app on google app engine, it gives an error as follow

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:567)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission(CustomSecurityManager.java:56)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkAccess(CustomSecurityManager.java:131)
at java.lang.ThreadGroup.checkAccess(ThreadGroup.java:315)
at java.lang.Thread.init(Thread.java:353)
at java.lang.Thread.<init>(Thread.java:479)
at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.<init>(IdleConnectionReaper.java:56)
at com.amazonaws.http.IdleConnectionReaper.registerConnectionManager(IdleConnectionReaper.java:62)
at com.amazonaws.http.ConnectionManagerFactory.createThreadSafeClientConnManager(ConnectionManagerFactory.java:30)
at com.amazonaws.http.HttpClientFactory.createHttpClient(HttpClientFactory.java:95)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.<init>(AmazonHttpClient.java:112)
at com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient.<init>(AmazonWebServiceClient.java:60)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:295)
at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<init>(AmazonS3Client.java:277)
at com.wa.gwtamazon.server.AmazonService.doPost(AmazonService.java:36)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:102)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:447)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:454)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:461)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext.runInContext(TraceContext.java:703)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:338)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:330)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:458)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

Comment: You might have to check across their document what permissions you are missing which gets caught in com.google.apphosting.runtime.security.CustomSecurityManager.checkPermission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't use the Amazon Libs because of restrictions in the Google App Engine (no Threads,no socket connection etc ...). But there are few solutions that should help you:

I find out solution from below link and its worked for me.

http://socialappdev.com/using-amazon-s3-with-google-app-engine-02-2011

Comment: Hi Divyesh. I know this is from a long time ago but I'm having this issue now and the link you provided no longer works. Can you remember what the solution was?

Comment: Hi, first you need to find out source code of LIB and copy all java files in your project. it will work.